# The modal and innerHTML values don't match when clicking the Print button

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to print data from my modal. The modal displays the proper value, but when I click the print button, the first data in my database appears.

Flow:

1. Admin Panel
2. Table containing the user data
3. Button of Modal
4. Modal with Print button
5. innerHTML for printing

I can't figure out what's wrong. Can someone help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function printDiv(){
  var divToPrint=document.getElementById('cts-card');
  var newWin=window.open('','_blank','height=600,width800');
  newWin.document.open();
  newWin.document.write('<html><title>ISKULTrace</title><style>.card-title{font-size:20px;}</style><body onload="window.print()">'+divToPrint.innerHTML+'</body></html>');
  newWin.document.close();
  setTimeout(function(){window.close();},750);
}
</script>
```

MODAL:

```
<button type="button" class="badge icon-left btn-dark" data-bs-toggle="modal"
  data-bs-target="#qr<?php echo $row['u_id'];?>">
<i class="fa fa-qrcode" aria-hidden="true"></i> QR Code
</button>
<!--Dark theme Modal -->
<div class="modal fade text-left" id="qr<?php echo $row['u_id'];?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel150" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable"
    role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header bg-dark white">
        <span class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel150">Card</span>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
          aria-label="Close">
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="cts-card" style="overflow: auto;" align="center">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <br>
              <div class="card-body">
                <table class="table table-bordered mb-0" style="width: 3.5in;border-collapse: collapse;">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="padding-top:5%;">
                      <img class="mx-auto d-block" src="../assets/images/logo/logo.png" alt="Logo" style="width: 70%;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                      <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="../temp/<?php echo $row['qr']; ?>.png" alt="Contact Tracing Card">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light-secondary"
          data-bs-dismiss="modal">
        <i class="bx bx-x d-block d-sm-none"></i>
        <span class="d-none d-sm-block"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Close</span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark ml-1" id="print-card" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onclick="printDiv();">
        <span class="d-none d-sm-block"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i> Print</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My best guess is that there is more than one HTML tag with the id `cts-card`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I double checked it and only the modal has the id of `cts-card`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware does the JS script only get the first data in a SQL query? I'm only using one modal for all the user and I just use the ID to show each data in the modal.

Comment: I cannot answer your first question, there's no code relating to that in your question. But... Your approach is basically correct: Have one modal, and load the "proper values" into it. If there's only one tag with the `cts-card` id in your HTML, and given your `printDiv()` function, which gets the content of that tag, it should print that. Clearly somewhere you've made a mistake, but I can't tell where. Are you properly using your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) to diagnose this problem?